# WebService in asp.net using visual studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

As we know, if we build web service using visual studio, visual studio automatically generate two files, the first one is .asmx and the second one is .vb as a code behind.

in code behind(.vb) what i got is like this :

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class WebService
 Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function

End Class
```

and in .asmx file, what i got is like this :

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/WebService.vb" Class="WebService" %>
```

the question is

1. what is the main purpose of .asmx file? it just show one row code, is it useful?
2. can we make some method is .asmx file and not in code_behind? and how to consume it from .aspx file?

Comment: Please refer the follwing links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149345/why-do-asmx-web-services-have-a-markup-file

Comment: @Selvam i just follow these instruction, but how  i can call method in .asmx file from .aspx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Refer below links:

[Why do asmx web services have a markup file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149345/why-do-asmx-web-services-have-a-markup-file)

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="WebService1" %>

using System.Web;      
using System.Web.Services;     

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]    
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]   
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]     
public class WebService1 : WebService     
{    

    [WebMethod]     
    public string HelloWorld()   
    {      
        return "Hello World";   
    }    
}
```

Comment: how i can call method helloworld() from .aspx file?

Comment: You don't want to call it from .aspx. I think you maybe don't understand what a web service is.

Comment: what i mean is:
<br />
dim ws as New WebService
<br />
ws.SomeMethod(Param1,Param2)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to sample vb coding

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB"  Class="WebService" %>
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld1() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function

End Class
```

Like other web method calls it is also listed in web method list .

left click your project Add Service Reference --> Discover ---> Expand + symbol

Web method should be listed there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manullay create the web rerference ( Add service refrence  )

webservice .asmx file sample

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB"  Class="WebService" %>
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld1() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function

End Class
```

change we config settings as below :

web.config code

```
<security mode="none">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
             realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>

<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
     <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
     <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
</security>
```

sample.aspx Page code

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.ServiceModel" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <%  Dim obj As New WebServiceSoapClient
        Response.Write(obj.HelloWorld1())%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```